# Need UltraTree Clone Method - Problem with reference

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultratree

I have ultraTree (infragistics  tree) which is created at design time and it has custom class as "Tag". I have List as member variable. I have two combo box. Based on the combo selection I'll check the List's each items "Tag". If list contains, just i pick that, otherwise i create a new UltraTree and add it to List and i assign to the Tree that is created at design time.

My problem is, what i adding to the collection gets reference and all the item in the collection are overwritten by the last item. UltraTree don't have any clone method.

I don't found any way to clone using this control.

What can be my solution  :(

My sample code is

```
// My custom class
SelectedDeviceState treeState = new SelectedDeviceState(
    firstDevice, secondDevice);

UltraTree tree = new UltraTree();

// This will clone the root node
// (it will be executed only once -> Root)
foreach (UltraTreeNode nod in tvwNavigation.Nodes)
{
    UltraTreeNode tnode = nod.Clone() as UltraTreeNode;
    tree.Nodes.Add(tnode);
}

//Adding the custom class as TAG
tree.Tag = treeState;

// Assigned and added
tvwNavigation = tree;
_treeCollection.Add(tree);
```

Comment: Don't give him grief, let's just get an editor to tart it up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a manual clone by writing a method that creates a new isntance of your type then assigns values to it from the original object.

In terms of a tree structure you would need to write a recursive clone, something like.

```
private ItemType CloneDeep(ItemType node)
{
    ItemType clone = new ItemType();
    clone.Property1 = node.Property1;
    clone.Property2 = node.Property2;

    foreach ( ItemType child in node.Nodes)
    {
        clone.Nodes.add(CloneDeep(child));
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Maybe look at [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

He wants to know how to get a copy of an object, rather than a copy of a reference to an object.

Answer (score 1):

There are some Reflection based methods you can use to deep-copy a custom object, google for "Reflection deep copy". This article, for example: http://alpatrick.blogspot.com/2005/01/prototype-pattern-using-reflection.html, clones all properties marked with a custom attribute [DeepCopy], but you can easily change that behavior yourself.

Also, there is a similar thread on SO: [How to deep copy between objects of different types in C#.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569154/how-to-deep-copy-between-objects-of-different-types-in-c-net)

**[Edit]** Note than in your example it may **not** be wise to simply create a complete deep copy of your tree node. A node may contain references to the tree, and other internal stuff which could possibly be unique and not copied to a different node.

In that case, you should simply **create a new node** (using a constructor), **assign the data** from the source node, and then **add the new node** to the tree.

The best way overall would be to bind your tree to you data, so that you **never** manually change the tree, but make it update automatically whenever you change your data. Check your Infragistics documentation on "data binding", that should be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SaveToBinary() method of UltraTree to clone.

the code should look like this:

```
void CloneTree() 
{
            //save the current tree into stream
            var savedTree = new MemoryStream();
            ultraTree1.SaveAsBinary(savedTree);
            byte[] buffer = savedTree.ToArray();
            savedTree.Close()

            //create a clone from the stream
            UltraTree newTree = new UltraTree();
            newTree.LoadFromBinary(new MemoryStream(buffer));
}
```

I hope this helps :-)