# C# trying to assign a class to another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to run the following code :

```
classA = classD;
```

to assign the values in `classA` to `classD` (the variable is being shared from another class called 'classC').

the above line would normally work in C++ but in C# its returning an error! is this possible in C#?

Comment: How are `classA` and `classD` related? What's the inheritance chain?

Comment: `class D : C` and `class A : D` so a variable is being copied from C to D and then from D to A.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi          so you want to copy a variable from class D to class A

Comment: yes but I was instructed to copy the classes and not the variables

Comment: What do you mean copy the classes? That makes no sense.

Comment: I was told that in C++ you can do the following : `classA = classB` and it will copy whatever variable they have in common. so I am not really sure

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031023/copy-a-class-c-sharp

Comment: I don't think you can, you may have to do it manually.

Comment: I think we need to see more code to put context to this question so someone can give you an appropriate answer. Also, it's possible your instructor just meant copy the class properties from one object to another.

Comment: Marc's answer is right. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments `A : D`, so all `A` are `D`, but not all `D` are necessarily `A`.

So with two variables:

```
A classA;
D classD = ...
```

We need

```
classA = (A) classD;
```

This does a type-check, to confirm that the specific `classD` **is** actually also an `A`. If this is the case (or it is `null`) then the assignment is successful; otherwise an exception occurs.

This is to prevent you assigning something to `classA` that is actually not really an `A`.

Note it is implicit the other way, since the compiler knows it to be valid:

```
classD = classA; // always valid - no type check
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking can you copy attributes of the same name from instances of different classes, then no.

Saying `classA = classB` where the classes are not related in the class hierarchy will cause a type error. If they are related, then all you are doing is changing the value of the variable `classA`, not copying anything.