# Object Shallow Copy in C#

Tags: c#, shallow-copy

I know to perform a shallow copy in C# we could use MemberwiseClone() function 
but I have an object inside a function and I want to take a copy of this object, so when I added to a list it won't refer to the same object when the object is changed 
here is my code

```
public void Do(object undoState)
    {
        _index += 1;
        if (_buffer.Count > _index)
            _buffer.RemoveRange(_index, _buffer.Count - _index);
        _buffer.Add(undoState);
    }
```

I want to copy the UndoState object to a new object and added to the buffer

thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1031062/939213

Comment: What you have stated here "take a copy of this object, so when I added to a list it won't refer to the same object" is a Deep copy wherein you do not simply create a copy of the reference to the Object but create a new object and copy the underlying values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface, and add your copy logic into it. Now instead of receiving an object in your Do method, use ICloneable.