# .NET - Is there the attribute [DataContract] for a Web Service?

Tags: .net, web-services, datacontract

note that I am not using WCF, i'm only using ASP.NET web service.
Anything similar?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`[DataContract]` is a feature of WCF, so no, the concept doesn't exist in standard ASMX webservices. You're limited to passing proxy objects back and forth, which can get messy.

[I've asked an equivalent question here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216884/force-net-webservice-to-use-local-object-class-not-proxy-class), and basically learned that you need WCF to do that kind of thing.

Comment: damn it!
what's the ideia by passing an object using XMLSerializer?
The client sends, and the method in web service recieves? But I cant use as parameter of the method, right?
=X
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not using WCF because Windows Phone doens't really support WCF yet =/