# Making remote method calls from objects returned by a web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, design-patterns

I have a web-method called `GetSessionData()` returning a `SessionData` object so defined:

```
public class SessionData
{
    private SalesDataDAO _dao;

    public SessionData()
    {
        this._dao = new SalesDataDAO();
        SessionId = 0;
    }

    public int SessionId { get; set}

    public string UserId { get; set}

    public string UserName { get; set}

    public string Group { get; set}

    // ...

    public SalesData GetSalesData()
    {
        SalesData sd = null;

        if (SessionId > 0)
        {
            sd = _dao.GetSalesData(SessionId);
        }

        return sd;
    }
}
```

Calling the `GetSessionData` method from the client I get a proxy object having only public properties.

Is there a way to use the `SessionData` object as if I was working with a local object?
How could I structure my object to obtain data from the WS in a transparent way?

**NOTE #1**
I'm not using WCF.

**NOTE #2**
The main issue is not to share the same type both on server and client side. What I'm just trying to achieve is retrieving the data from the server by `GetSalesData()` method.
Actually this method should do some kind of remote call...
Is there a way to obtain this? WCF is the right technology to solve this issue?
I'm not an expert of **RPC**...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216884/force-net-webservice-to-use-local-object-class-not-proxy-class#216924

Comment: is this using WCF? or 2.0-style web services? With the latter: you can't (conveniently)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm using classical web service, not WCF...

Comment: so I suppose I need to find another way to solve my problem... I think I'll extract the `GetSalesData` from my class and set it as a new web method in my service...

Comment: ASMX does not support this. One of many reasons to move to WCF.

Comment: @JohnSaunders can you please suggest me some helpful example or reference (about WCF) that address my specific issue?

Comment: When you use "Add Service Reference" to create a proxy, you can check a box that says to reuse the types. Simply add a reference in the client project to the assembly containing the type, and both the client and service can use the same exact class. Trivial.