# How to generate proxy class from WSDL in case of webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

suppose when i have only wsdl file then how can i create proxy class just to call webservice various method. how webservice related all class and its property & method will be exposed in my c# apps. can anyone help guiding me. thanks

Comment: Search for `wsdl.exe` or `svcutil.exe`

Comment: thanks but how far i know svcutil is related with WCF not webservice but i am not sure...put some light.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx - note MS recommends using svcutil.exe over wsdl.exe as the latter is considered legacy technology.

Comment: I answered this question in here:
[Force .NET web-service to use local object class, not proxy class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78008794)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to use the [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx), or Visual Studio's [Add Service Reference Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) in order to generate a client proxy for the service with which you want to communicate. The generated proxy will provide classes that abstract the service contract, and you can program your client applications to interact with these classes.

Comment: when we add web reference then we need to know the webservice url but in some cases i have seen 3rd party company provide only wsdl file. if i generate proxy from wsdl then how proxy can interact with webservice. how proxy class know the actual url of webservice.....can u discuss this concept

Comment: any how webservice url is stored in wsdl file? in which tag it is stored. please give me sample wsdl code just to point out how web service url is stored in wsdl file. thanks

Comment: The proxy, as generated, has no information regarding the endpoint of the service. When you instantiate the proxy (or a channel), you must provide the binding and endpoint to be used. This information can also be read from a configuration file, which the tools mentioned above will also generate. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx

Comment: In the WSDL file the service endpoint information is under <definitions>/<service>/<port>/<address>

Answer (score 8):

There is an utility, it shipps with Visual Studio (since 2005, I think), called [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

It's commandline, and can be used to generate proxy.

Comment: when we add web reference then we need to know the webservice url but in some cases i have seen 3rd party company provide only wsdl file. if i generate proxy from wsdl then how proxy can interact with webservice. how proxy class know the actual url of webservice.....can u discuss this concept

Comment: Same as proxy added by reference. Proxy itself doesn't contain information about WebService location. Web Service configuration is in Web.config/app.config file. Adding webreference generates client configuration. When adding proxy by Yourself You'll have to add configuration by Yourself. Alternatively You should be able to pass URL as a client constructor parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WSDL.exe tool using command line.

i.e. `WseWsdl3 WSDLPath /out:MyProxyClass.cs`

Comment: syntax is wrong i think. when we add web reference then we need to know the webservice url but in some cases i have seen 3rd party company provide only wsdl file. if i generate proxy from wsdl then how proxy can interact with webservice. how proxy class know the actual url of webservice.....can u discuss this concept.

Comment: WSDL does have a Service address as in <soap:address> tag. once you generate a proxy it should generate a configuration value in your config that will determine which Service URL to use for an interaction.

Answer (score 1):

if WseWsdl3.exe is unable to create the proxy class, there is still a way.

If you can run your service as a regular ASP.NET web application in IIS, it creates temporary ASP.NET files where the proxy class is nicely generated for you.

You can find it in folder:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vMAJOR.MINOR.BUILD\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\YOUR_WEB_APP.

There are some subfolders with random names, go to most recent one and look something like "App_WebReferences.XXXX.0.cs".